# key($data) not working as expected when value = 0?

Tags: php

i have a while loop, it goes like so....

```
        while ($fruit_name = current($data)) {
            $string1 .= "'".key($data)."',";
            next($data);
        }
```

this works perfectly, and echos:

```
'derp','test'
```

when the array data =

```
Array ( [derp] => 68 [test] => 1 )
```

but, if the array data =

```
Array ( [derp] => 0 [test] => 0 )
```

it echos

```
  nothing,
```

what do?

Comment: You'd be better off using foreach to wrap quotes and then joining on a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to traverse an array manually, you must use [`each`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) since there is - as you found out - no way to differentiate the negative result from `current` and a false-valued value. Even if you were to check with `=== false`, you'd still fail if the array contained a `false` entry.

However, you should really just use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) instead:

```
foreach ($data as $k=>$fruit_name) {
    $string1 .= "'". $k . "',";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP counts 0 as false which terminates your while loop, to allow 0 you would need to do a type-sensitive comparison:

```
while (($fruit_name = current($data)) !== false) {
    $string1 .= "'".key($data)."',";
    next($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want a comma delimited list of keys from your array, regardless of their values, a combination of [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) might be a better approach

```
$string = implode(',', array_keys($data));
```